# Calculating TF-IDF from a Pandas DataFrame (without sklearn)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

So I have a Pandas DataFrame: 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuU0E.png)

And as you can see, I've labelled it to make it a bit clearer (the book titles are simply names of the books and the numbers are their respective frequencies).

To calculate TF-IDF, I have to implement a function named "choice" with the signature as below:

```
def choice(term, documents):
```

Where "term" is any valid word that exists in the dataframe and "documents" is the pandas dataframe itself. The function calculates the TF-IDF for all the books in the dataframe (thus, rows, as each book is a new row) and then returns the name of the book which has the highest TF-IDF value like:

```
choice('the', mydataframe)

# output: pg16238.txt
```

The problem I am encountering is that I am unable to extract a particular frequency from the dataframe owing to having renamed the indexing from standard numbering (0, 1, 2, etc) to the book titles as you can see in the image which renders the built-in ".str.contains" function useless somehow (it doesn't work).

I searched a lot about it and found out that it somehow became a "multi-index" dataframe? (I am a beginner so I do not have a good idea about how to tackle this).

Another problem I am having is that I do not know how to return the name of the book after the calculation is completed. Like, should I make a list of the indexes and then create a dictionary which looks something like:

```
{'book-title': tf-idf-value}
```

and then return the highest value? Please help me in figuring out the appropriate way to solve this.

I have successfully written a working IDF calculation function:

```
def get_IDF(self, term):
    N = 0
    D = len(self.files_list)
    for file in self.files_list:
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='replace') as f:
            temp_cleaned_data = ''.join(i.lower() for i in f.read() if ord(i) < 128).translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).replace('\n', ' ')
            if self.contains_word(temp_cleaned_data, term):
                N += 1
    return 1 + (math.log(D / (1 + N)))
```

"files_list" is a list of files stored in the current directory.

Also, please excuse my terrible coded "temp_cleaned_data", I will refactor it later so sorry about that. ( I know there are really simpler ways to do this using ".isalnum()" but I am trying to learn a bit of list comprehension and functional programming too so I try out different stuff and piece it together to see how it works).

Anyways, I'd really appreciate any sort of help in figuring this out, thank you. The formula for TF-IDF is:

> term-frequency(term) x idf(term)

**Note**: The DataFrame screenshot I provides is only a part of the complete dataframe. Also, the book-titles may vary and the amount of books is not just 6 and can be N in number. Thus, I intend to code the function which can factor in the above mentioned conditions.

Comment: Hi. I'm still looking at this, but you can use `.loc[index,column]` for rows/columns.  Example: `df.loc['11-0.txt','accept'] = 0.000034` will set that cell to 0.000034, like in your screenshot.

Comment: @MarkMoretto But how will I iterate because the index is not numbered and is a book title now?

Comment: What's the value in the DataFrame you provided? Is it the term frequency already?

Comment: @snowneji yes, the values are term frequencies as calculated by (term/total terms in text file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little modification to your implementation, I assume you've already calculated the IDF DataFrame. Let's create a dummy one of some uniform values:

```
IDF = pd.DataFrame([1.0/len(df.index)]*len(df.index), index = df.index)
print(IDF)


                0
11-0.txt     0.166667
1342-0.txt   0.166667
1661-0.txt   0.166667
1952-0.txt   0.166667
84-0.txt     0.166667
pg16328.txt  0.166667
```

I also change your name of `df` to `TF`:

```
TF = df.copy()



def choice(term, TF, impute_val=0.000001):
    TF = TF.fillna(impute_val)

    # Based on the formula provided, calculate the TFIDF score for all documents of this term
    tfidf_score = TF[term].values.ravel() * IDF.values.ravel()

    doc_names = TF.index.tolist()
    # sort by TFIDF score and return the doc name that has max tfidf value
    return sorted(zip(doc_names,tfidf_score),key=lambda x: x[1])[-1][0]

print(choice(term='accept', TF=TF))

'1661-0.txt'
```

Comment: Wow, this is indeed so informative! Will this also work if there are "NaN" values in the dataset (because I have a lot of them as well as you can see here: https://i.imgur.com/aa3UL2W.png)

Comment: How are you going to handle NaN's? Assigning a very small value? Or impute as 0? Anyway, I'll edit the function and you can choose the imputation method

Comment: I was also thinking to impute it to 0 as dictionaries do not handle NaNs well right?

Comment: 0 is fine, and some people might smooth it to assign a very small float I think.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help as this was quite confusing for a beginner like me. I am new to ".ravel()" but now when I see the docs it seems quintessential and it was a grave error on my part to need read the docs properly. Your lamda function is brilliant btw haha!

Comment: No problem, glad to help =)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but could you have a look at my "get_IDF()" function and show me how to improve it? I feel that its really hacky as even after having the term frequencies in my dataframe, I am still accessing the files again to count the value of N. Thus, please show me how can I calculate N (number of books that contain the given term, thus counting rows which have that term) by using the dataframe itself.

Comment: If you've had TF dataframe calculated, there is no need to calculate IDF one by one, the Document Frequency can be calculated directly: `(df>0).sum(axis=0)/len(df)`. Based on this result, you can add the `log` and `inverse` on it

Comment: Thanks again! This is indeed a straightforward solution.